# Xamarin - Create a ListView with images and fill it with List of Object

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm relatively new to Xamarin.Android and am looking to build something I did in WPF in Xamarin as an Android App.

In WPF I used an `ItemsControl` with an `Image` Tag and then bound them to it.
In Xamarin I have not found something like this though (only the `RepeaterView` which I found quite hard to figure out/implement it with images).

It should look like this:

[image: Preview of the App]

I would like to populate this `ListView` (if it is one) with a `List<Object>` and load the URL of the images, stored in a property in the `Object`, into one Image each.

Now my question, how would I do it theoretically? I'm looking for keywords/tutorials/documentations on classes/controls that allow me to do something like that.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view) is what you want. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view) and [this](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/layout/grid_view/create_a_grid_view) tutorials which show how to create apps looking like

[image]
<sub>(source: [xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/layout/grid_view/create_a_grid_view/Images/gridview.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/Images/HelloViews4.png))</sub>

So you should create a [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view) and populate [`ImageView`](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/controls/imageview)s as item and `SetImageBitmap()` from your `List<>`.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Android has a built-in `GridView` control, which are described in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html/). Xamarin also provides its own documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/).

Each list control in android has an `Adapter` which is basically a provider of items for the control. The most appropriate solution for you is to create a class derived from `BaseAdapter<T>`, which is generic and can take the type you require. The items inside the adapter are then loaded as items into the `ListView`. This process is [well described here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/).

Now you can create a custom item layout to display the images and "bind" the control properties inside the `getView` method of the custom adapter. Once again, for more information, you can see the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/).

Also I would recommend you to not use `List<Object>` but create a strongly typed list, which will have the properties you need. This will ensure better type safety.